# Google sheets: replace a 5 character string with corresponding characters

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a column representing status of the last 5 runs. Each status is represented by a unique character. I want to replace these characters with an 'O' of a colour.

Example: status: ggryn
I want to replace all g's with green, r with red and so on.

Is there any formula I can use to make this process easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this (with your column of statuses in A1 downwards):

```
=arrayformula(map(tocol(A1:A,1),lambda(each,concatenate(xlookup(regexextract(each,rept("(.)",len(each))),{"r";"y";"g"},{"";"";""},)))))
```

We can't use a formula to generate individually-coloured O's (as standard formatting is metadata so is 'beyond the reach' of a formula, and conditional formatting applies text colouring to the entire contents of cells. A workaround is to exploit the fact that unicode fonts contain coloured shape characters like I've used here, and simply substitute them in using multiple replacement as I've done here. Note that you didn't define how the 'n' in your example should be dealt with, so I've use XLOOKUP's *missing value* argument to replace it with a blank.